# java Main < inputfile does not work (Main is a java Class to test an ANTLR grammar)

Tags: java, error-handling, io, redirect, antlr3

I am trying to test an ANTLR grammar with such  a  standard test rig

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SampleLexer lexer = new SampleLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]));
    SampleParser parser = new SampleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.program();
  }
}
```

I have a test file called mytest00. Now I want to use this file as input. I suppose I am doing a stardard IO redirection here.

```
   bash-3.2$ java Main < mytest00
```

But it gives me such an error message. What is the problem please? Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Main.main(SampleTest.java:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use `args[0]` but you haven't actually passed in any command line arguments - you've just redirected a file into the standard input of the process. So the array has no elements, and you're getting an exception because you're trying to get the first element of that empty array.

It's not really clear that you *actually* want `ANTLRStringStream`. I suspect you want `ANTLRInputStream` wrapping `System.in` if `args.length == 0`, and `ANTLRFileStream(args[0])` otherwise.

Comment: Sorry would you please be more precise? I really cannot catch it. What would you propose to do? I think my program is waiting for an input through its arg[0] parameter, and the standard input is the actual value that arg[0] will take. Shouldn't it work like that?? Thanks.

Comment: @zell: No, it shouldn't work like that. There's a big difference between the standard input of the program and the arguments used to invoke it. What would you expect it to do if you'd written `java Main foo bar < mytest00`? In that case, `args` would be `{ "foo", "bar" }`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But what would be a neat way to treat my input file as the input of the ANTLR test rig? Thanks. For information, I had used gunit for that purpose, but the problem of gunit to me is it provides no useful error message. So it would be nice to have a file as direct input of the JAVA Main.

Comment: @zell: As I said in my answer, I suspect you want an `ANTLRFileStream` which lets you pass in a filename - or you can use `ANTLRInputStream` wrapping `System.in` if you still want the stdin redirection.

Comment: @zell, note that when using `ANTLRFileStream(args[0])` as @Jon suggested, you need to drop the `<` from `java Main < mytest00`, making that: `java Main mytest00`

Comment: Thank you for all your replies and comments. Very helpful. Really appreciate. And it works now!

Comment: By the way, those ANTLR interpreters are so buggy that you can never, ever count on them. Since one week, I have had a dozen of examples where the interpreters report fautive errors.

Comment: @zell, by "ANTLR interpreters" you probably mean the interpreter in ANTLRWorks (it's just one). The debugger from ANTLRWorks works perfect, however.

Comment: @Bart. Is there any other interpreter? You said Eclipse IDE used the same interpreter as ANTLRWorks.

Comment: @zell, no, AFAIK, there's only one: ANTLRWorks' interpreter (used by the Eclipse plugin). Because you used interpreters (plural), I thought you were talking about more than one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4750/discussion-between-zell-and-bart-kiers)

Answer (score 2):

when you use `<` as parameter , OS treats it as input redirection . so it will check for it and it won't  pass argument the java `main()`

Answer (score 2):

**What the exception means and how to deal with exceptions generally**

```
at Main.main(SampleTest.java:5)
```

The problem appears in 5 line of your code, which is:

```
SampleLexer lexer = new SampleLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]));
```

and the Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

which means you're trying to retrieve 0-element from your array `args`, the array has been accessed with an illegal index because the array is empty (size=0)

---

**Example solution**

You want to use this constructor:

```
public ANTLRStringStream(String str)
```

To do this you can:

1. read standard input to some String
2. pass this String to `ANTLRStringStream` constructor